# How to sum variables in template vue?

Tags: vue.js, flask

now i'm working in VUE and i need to sum variables. In python (flask), i've been using such a code

```
<!-- Creating vars (I have already created vars in data ())-->
    {% set transitions = namespace(amount=0) %}
    {% set downloads = namespace(amount=0) %}
    {% set registered = namespace(amount=0) %}
    {% set played = namespace(amount=0) %}

    {% for stat in stats %}
        <!-- So i need such a code in VUE -->
        {% set transitions.amount = transitions.amount + stat[1] | int %}
        {% set downloads.amount = downloads.amount + stat[2] | int %}
        {% set registered.amount = registered.amount + stat[3] | int %}
        {% set played.amount = played.amount + (stat[4] / 60) | round | int %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ stat[5] }}</td>
        <td>{{ stat[1] }}</td>
        <td>{{ stat[2] }}</td>
        <td>{{ stat[3] }}</td>
        <td>{{ (stat[4] / 60)|round|int}}</td>
        <td>{{ stat[0] }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

So i need to 'convert' it to vue like:

```
{{ var1 += stat[1] }}
```

OK, i wrote such a dumy code:

```
<tr v-for="promo in promoStats" :key="promo.ID">
                <td>{{ promo.date }}</td>
                <td>{{ sumTransfers(promo.transitions) }}</td>
                <td>{{ sumDownloads(promo.downloads) }}</td>
                <td>{{ sumRegisters(promo.registered) }}</td>
                <td>{{ sumHours(Math.round(promo.hoursPlayed / 60))}}</td>
              </tr>
```

Script:

```
methods: {
    sumTransfers (val) {
      this.transitions += val
      console.log(this.transitions)
      return val
    },
    sumDownloads (val) {
      this.downloads += val
      return val
    },
    sumRegisters (val) {
      this.registered += val
      return val
    },
    sumHours (val) {
      this.played += val
      return val
    }
  }
```

And i recieve an error:

> **You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.**

Comment: You should just calculate everything in your script and then just display the values in template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do it is by calling a method:

```
<template>
  <td>{{ sumStats(var1, stat[0]) }}</td> <!-- 12 + 1 -->
  <td>{{ sumStats(var1, stat[1]) }}</td> <!-- 12 + 2 -->
  <td>{{ sumStats(var1, stat[2]) }}</td> <!-- 12 + 3 -->
  <td>{{ sumStats(6, 5) }}</td> <!-- 6 + 5 -->
</template>
```

In the script tag:

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    var1: 12,
    stat: [1,2,3,4,5]
  }),
  methods: {
    sumStats(num1, num2) {
      return num + num2;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm guessing that you have something like:

```
promotions: [{
    date: 'somedate',
    transitions: 1,
    downloads: 2,
    registered: 3,
    played: 4,
  },{
    date: 'somedate2',
    transitions: 5,
    downloads: 6,
    registered: 7,
    played: 8,
  }
]
```

If you want to show each object in one row :

```
<tr v-for="promo in promotions">
    <td>{{ promo.date }}</td>
    <td>{{ promo.transitions }}</td>
    <td>{{ promo.downloads }}</td>
    <td>{{ promo.registered }}</td>
    <td>{{ promo.played }}</td>
</tr>
```

Then you get:

```
<tr>
    <td>somedate</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>somedate2</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr>
```

Now, if you want only one row with the sum of each variable, this is the way to do it:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!--  Show each promotion information in one row -->
    <tr v-for="promo in promotions">
      <td>{{ promo.date }}</td>
      <td>{{ promo.transitions }}</td>
      <td>{{ promo.downloads }}</td>
      <td>{{ promo.registered }}</td>
      <td>{{ promo.played }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!--  Show the sum of all the variables in one row -->
      <td>Empty date</td>
      <td>{{ totalpromotions.totalTransitions }}</td>
      <td>{{ totalPromotions.totalDownloads }}</td>
      <td>{{ totalPromotions.totalRegistered }}</td>
      <td>{{ totalPromotions.totalPlayed }}</td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      promotions: [{
        date: 'somedate',
        transitions: 1,
        downloads: 2,
        registered: 3,
        played: 4,
      },{
        date: 'somedate2',
        transitions: 5,
        downloads: 6,
        registered: 7,
        played: 8,
      }]
    }),
    computed: {
      totalPromotions() {
        const accumulator = {
          totalDownloads: 0,
          totalPlayed: 0,
          totalRegistered: 0,
          totalTransitions: 0
        }
        // sum each promotion variable
        this.promotions.forEach(promotion => {
          accumulator.totalDownloads += promotion.downloads;
          accumulator.totalPlayed += promotion.played;
          accumulator.totalRegistered += promotion.registered;
          accumulator.totalTransitions += promotion.transitions
        });
        return accumulator;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, i'll try it

Comment: I would like to know what is the functionality that you want to achieve, also, the way to sum variables is as the code I share, but you want to do something different, so maybe the question is not explaining what you want to do in your code. Let me know more about it, then I can add additional information to my proposed solution :D, maybe you can share the whole component code.

Comment: So, in loop i show the promo stats as downloads, hours played e.t.c. And i need to get sum of all fields (total downloads, total transitions) and display it

Comment: The best way to do it, is to have calculated the values, I mean, yo can have a computed property with all the data, and use methods to get the values and return a unique variable with the table information, are you adding new data to the table through a http request? or do you have all the data inside the data property? Can you share your promotions object please?

Comment: P.S i know that i can use sql to get sum of all fields, buy i need exactly in vue code

Comment: Share the object that you have stored in the promotions variable, then I can show you how to use it in a computed variable.

Comment: Total stats: transitions
Data from DB: promo.transitions

Comment: Thanks so much, now its working fine :)
P.S I fix some errors in your code

Comment: No problem! Hahaha writing blocks of code in the stackoverflow editor is annoying sometimes, I'll try to use some tools like codepen to help, anyway, glad to know that it was helpful